# SonarQube not showing anything on my JavaScript Maven sub-module

Tags: javascript, maven, sonarqube

I have a multi-module Maven project with 2 modules: one is a Java project the other one is a JavaScript project using the front-end Maven plugin that runs gulp.

I get my Java code checked by Sonar and code coverage for that as well. However, the Javascript module (shown as a 'component' in Sonar) does seem to have been recognized as such. Do I need to do something for Sonar to 'see' this is a JavaScript module?

I am using SonarQube 5.2 and the JavaScript plugin is installed. (I can see 'Sonar Way' quality profile for JavaScript under 'Quality Profiles')

UPDATE:

- Java plugin has version 3.8
- JavaScript plugin has version 2.9
- See http://pastebin.com/Rv0qffjs for log

Comment: Would you mind sharing the log of the analysis and precise the sonar java plugin version as well as the sonar javascript plugin version ?

Comment: Question updated with requested info.

Answer (score 0):

Your logs show that no file is indexed for "MyProject Admin Client":

```
[INFO] -------------  Scan MyProject Admin Client
[INFO] Base dir: /Users/wdb/Projects/myproject/myproject-admin-client
[INFO] Working dir: /Users/wdb/Projects/myproject/myproject-admin-client/target/sonar
[INFO] Source paths: pom.xml
[INFO] Binary dirs: target/classes
[INFO] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
[INFO] Index files
[INFO] 0 files indexed
```

You have to configure the `sonar.sources` property so that your JavaScript files are indexed. Please see the documentation of the [SonarQube Scanner for Maven](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-AnalyzingaMulti-languageProject).

Comment: And where do I set `sonar.sources` ? Is this in the `pom.xml` of `MyProject Admin Client` ?

Comment: My JavaScript files are in `src/main/js`. If I set `<sourceDirectory>src/main/js</sourceDirectory>` in the `pom.xml`, then it works. Using `src/main` alone does not work, unless I just add an empty `test.js` file in `src/main`. Would this be considered a bug? I would expect that it would search subdirectories as well.

Comment: Could you provide the debug logs of that case, please (with -X)?